# Numberfield and dropdown box in same grid cell

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6.5

I trying to make both numberfield and dropdown box in same grid cell. But I haven't got the correct solution. Can anyone knows about logic Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [hbox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.HBox.html) layout [fieldcontainer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldContainer.html) for wrap you components.

```
           {
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                flex: 1,
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        flex: 1
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        flex: 1
                    }, ]
                }
            }
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32vp)

Comment: I just wanted to write the same solution, you were faster ;)

Comment: Thanks for you help. But this solution is not seems to be working inside the treepanel grid cell. It hiding the numberfield also.

Comment: You did not indicate this in the question. But still, this solution is suitable for wood.
https://i.imgur.com/zp660g6.png